How to get Minifi UI Portal
I wanted to work on the minifi, which is a lighter version of Apache NiFi project.
Current I pulled the minifi image from docker hub, using

docker pull apache/nifi-minifi:latest

Now I do not know which port I should expose on my local, so that I could get my local minifi running over the browser and build the flow I want.

There will be a default port exposed when you start  an container for this image. To get the UI for building the flow you need to start a nifi server and a c2 server also. You can refer this article for it article

yeah Suresh, but it would not even get the UI for minifi like we have for nifi. Because I wanted to search for if I could see the flow running over the minifi like we do on nifi.

After reading the documentation:

I learned that MiNiFi is a subproject of NiFi, designed to be as lightweight as possible. Unlike NiFi, MiNiFi runs purely as a backend application without any UI.

To create data flows, you use NiFi to design the flow and then convert the NiFi XML templates into YAML format using the MiNiFi toolkit, allowing MiNiFi to process them. That's the entire workflow.
